# Proper way to Thread a foreach loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, foreach, c#-3.0

I have been cracking at this for the last 30 minutes, trying to thread a simple `foreach` loop which is casting some error no matter what I do (*First time not using a threading framework so I'm most likely making some silly syntax mistake*)

Sadly I cant use `Parallel.For` due to having to stay .net 3.5 or below... Can someone tell me the right way to do this so I can go back to not wanting to scream!!

*Sudo code*

```
void SomeMethod
{
    foreach(Touch Input in Inputlist){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.FilterInput(Input)));
        thread.Start();
    }
}
void FilterInput(Input UnFilteredInput){
....
}
```

Edit: MonoDevelop is casting the following errors

1. Expression denotes a value, where a type or method group was
   expected
2. The best overloaded method match for
   System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ThreadStart) has
   some invalid arguments,
3. Argument #1 cannot convert object expression to type
   System.Threading.ThreadStart

Comment: Try adding a `Touch copy = Input;` line at the top of your loop and changing the thread start to `Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.FilterInput(copy)));`

Comment: Still casting the same 3 errors even with that ::  `(Expression denotes a value, where a type or method group was expected), (The best overloaded method match for System.Threading.Thread.Thread (System.Threading.ThreadStart) has some invalid arguments), (3: Argument #1 cannot convert object expression to type System.Threading.ThreadStart)`

Comment: casting errors aside, you are likely going to create way too many threads unless you put a Semaphore in the loop or something.

Comment: Its an a closed update system *No more then 8 inputs a tick, no more then 50 ticks per second* so Im hoping that will not be an issue

Comment: You're creating 400 threads per second? Have you considered using a `ThreadPool`?

Comment: Good point Andrew :: this is what happens when I'm coding at 1:00 am :) .... A ThreadPool is 100% the way to go !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, for something like this you should use a lighter weight ThreadPool intead of a full Thread. (Also you did make some casting mistakes too, the thread pool version uses the same style as Thread so you can see the difference)

```
void SomeMethod
{
    foreach(Touch input in Inputlist){
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(FilterInput), input);
    }
}
void FilterInput(object unCastUnFilteredInput){
    Touch UnFilteredInput = (Touch)unCastUnFilteredInput;
....
}
```

However I would still be worried about creating too many threads per second and would recomend some kind of blocking to meter the rate new threads can be created.

```
const int MaxConcurrentThreads = 4;

private readonly Semaphore _inputLimiter = new Semaphore(MaxConcurrentThreads,MaxConcurrentThreads);

void SomeMethod
{
    foreach(Touch input in Inputlist){
        _inputLimiter.WaitOne();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(FilterInput), input);
    }
}
void FilterInput(object unCastUnFilteredInput){
    try
    {
        Touch UnFilteredInput = (Touch)unCastUnFilteredInput;
        ....
    {
    finally
    {
        //use a try-finally so the semaphore still gets released in the event a exception happens in the .... region.
        _inputLimiter.Release();
    }
}
```